# How to get a dual boot Windows XP and 7 setup on laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot

I've had a dual boot option before with windows and Kubuntu but Linux took care of that. Now I have windows 7 already on the laptop but I need XP as well. Is it as easy as just putting in the XP disk and it will take care of setting up a partition and boot selection at startup or do I need to know how to do it? thanks.

Comment: Do you have the Windows 7 install disk? Not a OEM recovery disk, the actual install disk.

Comment: For doing things the other way around, installing Windows 7 after Windows XP to get a dual boot system, see [this SuperUser question](http://superuser.com/questions/306587).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving to superuser but-
Easiest way is probably to shrink the win7 partitions using the ubuntu live cd.
Install xp into the new partition.
Windows7 and XP will see each other, they will just put the other system disk as 'd:'

ps. If this is just an occasional need to run something under XP then you could install XP into virtualPC or Virtualbox.

Comment: If they're on the same hard drive how would you then select which OS boots at start up?

Comment: Either install a separate boot manager like Grub/Lilo or windows can do it with the startup options. Set the Windows7 drive as the main bootable partition and let it handle it